# More complex Flask app does not run on Apache 2.4

Tags: python, apache, flask

I have a Flask app (using factory pattern) that I wanted to finally deploy on a production server. It worked fine in developer mode (so server that Flask uses for development and testing), but now wanted to run this on Apache 2.4.

And I was able to start Hello World Flask app, but when I use the same config for my target app it does not want to start.

Here's the config:

**VHost**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apps/FinanceManagementAppPython2"
    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Apps/FinanceManagementAppPython2/index/web.wsgi"
    <Directory C:/Apps/FinanceManagementAppPython2>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "C:/Apps/FinanceManagementAppPython2/error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/Apps/FinanceManagementAppPython2/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**web.wsgi**

```
import sys
 
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Apps/FinanceManagementAppPython2')
 
from start import launch_app_in_apache
application = launch_app_in_apache()
```

**start.py**

```
#Flask
from app import create_app
from config import WorkDevelopmentConfig, WorkProductionConfig, Config
# Logger
import logging

def launch_app_in_apache():
    # LOGGING
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename = 'status.log', 
        encoding = 'utf-8', 
        filemode = 'w',
        level = logging.DEBUG, 
        format = "%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s", 
        datefmt = "%H:%M:%S"
        )

    # RUN FLASK WEBAPP
    app = create_app(Config)
    return(app)
```

What is wrong? I test this simply using `localhost:80` and Hello World works. I suspect that `launch_app_in_apache` function might not be appropriate, but mod_wsgi suggest using link to crate_app as application (I do the same as my function is basically a wrapper around `create_app` to define logger parameters).

Any ideas? How do debug it?

Comment: Guys, any ideas how to solve that?